# Not sure if current data structure is appropriate

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
PN | LastS | CurrentS  | Price
111111 | 100001 | 100002 | 28
111111 | 100001 | 100001 | 32
111111 | 100001 | 100004 | 48
111111 | 100001 | 100003 | 19
222222 | 100004 | 100001 | 200
222222 | 100004 | 100003 | 236
222222 | 100002 | 100005 | 397
222222 | 100003 | 100006 | 302
```

Sorry guys, initially the question was unclear, my fault. So, column LastS stands for previous suppliers and column CurrentS stands for Current Supplier. 
I would like to find out for a given part number (in our case 111111 or 222222):

1) If all previous suppliers are the same, i.e all values in column LastS are the same for each PN ( rows 1,2,3,4 stand for the same PN). In this case - 100001. If this is the true, then find this value in column CurrentS( but iterate for only first PN - 111111). Then in our case we find it on row 2 and take the respective price from column Price and put it in new column New Price.

2) If the previous suppliers for a given part number are not the same as in the case with PN - 222222, we take the last row for this PN(last row of column LastS-100003) and proceed with the same logic as one ( find the value on row 6 in column CurrentS and take the respective Price)

I have tried to run a for loop, groupby the 'PN' column and then check if max() == min() for column 'LastS'. If this is true I am not sure how to proceed and if it is possible given the current data structure.

I expect the final outcome to be presented this way:

```
PN | LastS | CurrentS  | Price | New Price
111111 | 100001 | 100002 | 28 | 32
111111 | 100001 | 100001 | 32 | 32
111111 | 100001 | 100004 | 48 | 32
111111 | 100001 | 100003 | 48 | 32
222222 | 100004 | 100001 | 200 | 236
222222 | 100004 | 100003 | 236 | 236
222222 | 100002 | 100005 | 397 | 236
222222 | 100003 | 100006 | 302 | 236
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. If you're saying "for each row, check whether the LastS for that row is the same as CurrentS for that row", then it doesn't make any sense to search for that CurrentS. If that's not what you mean, then I can only speculate what you do mean.

Comment: Is CurrentS not duplicated within each group?

Comment: I think he means 1) if there exists a row where currents = lasts output the price from that row r to all rows sharing a PIN with r, otherwise 2) no idea (possible take the price from the last row when sorted by lasts then currents)

Comment: I don't get how do you reach that desired output. According to your question (and specifically condition 2). Just as an example, according to what you say you should have New Price=48 in line 6 (last appearance of 10003 is in line 4 and its Price is 48).

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but it seems to be for each group 1. Take the last Value in LastS. Based on that value. 2. find the row with that value in Current S 3. Use the price of that row.

Comment: Guys, I have edited the post, it was a complete mess before, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You really have one condition; if the values are all the same then you still want to take the last `LastS` value.

We get that last value, then merge to select the correct `CurrentS` row, and bring the price for each PN back with a map:

```
df1 = df.groupby('PN').LastS.last().to_frame('CurrentS').reset_index()
s = df.merge(df1).rename(columns={'Price': 'New Price'}).set_index('PN')['New Price']

df['New Price'] = df['PN'].map(s)
```

#### Output:

```
       PN   LastS  CurrentS  Price  New Price
0  111111  100001    100002     28         32
1  111111  100001    100001     32         32
2  111111  100001    100004     48         32
3  111111  100001    100003     19         32
4  222222  100004    100001    200        236
5  222222  100004    100003    236        236
6  222222  100002    100005    397        236
7  222222  100003    100006    302        236
```